# How to display Python console output in browser using Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Deleting the question as no reply received after waiting for long period.

Comment: Just do the flask Tutorial, after 10 Minutes u can do this.https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-ii-templates